# Using BitmapDat for Sprite

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, events

I am trying to get the bitmapdata from a MovieClip and create a Sprite with it, because I want to use this Sprite as a mask for the MovieClip, but I don;t know how. I have looked around on how I could do this, but I didn't find anything. Can someone help me?

EDIT: Also, how will I be able to edit its contents afterwards? For example, how would I change its color?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To draw a `MovieClip` onto a `BitmapData` object:

```
var bitmapData:BitmapData = new BitmapData(mc.width, mc.height);
bitmapData.draw(mc);
```

Then there are a few functions to manipulate the bitmap data (e.g. `colorTransform()`).

To draw the bitmap data onto a `Sprite` instance, see `Sprite.graphics.beginBitmapFill()`

```
var sprite:Sprite = new Sprite();
var g:Graphics = sprite.graphics;

g.beginBitmapFill(bitmapData, null, false);
g.drawRect(0, 0, bitmapData.width, bitmapData.height);
g.endFill();
```

Answer (score 0):

There is prob much more easy way to achive your problem. If you could explain what you are trying to do. It would be easier to ans.

Easiest way, link movieclip to a class and create an instance of it. hope this helps.